# SELECT and ORDER BY that column using COUNT from another table

Tags: php, mysql

My scenario is this:

I have 3 tables with structures as follows:

```
articles: article_id, more data;
tags: tag_id, tag_name, more data;
article_tags: article_tag_id, tag_id, article_id
```

Each article can have multiple tags. I want to retrieve the tags of an article (article_id is provided) ordered by the total number of times that tag was used.

For Eg:

```
Article1 has tags 'tag4', 'tag3', 'tag2'
Article2 has tags 'tag4', 'tag3'
Article3 has tags 'tag4'
Article4 has tags 'tag4', 'tag3', 'tag2', 'tag1'
```

So when I am looking for the tags of article4, it should order it so:

```
1. tag4 (4 occurrences)
2. tag3 (3 occurrences)
3. tag2 (2 occurrences)
4. tag1 (1 occurrence)
```

Is this possible with one MySql query?
Currently I am just retrieving all the tags of that article, then another array with the list of tags ordered by occurrences, then just manually sorting the former array using the later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's

```
SELECT t.tag_name, COUNT(at.*) as total
  FROM tags t
  JOIN article_tags at ON at.tag_id=t.tag_id
 WHERE t.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM article_tags at2 WHERE at2.article_id = ?)
 GROUP BY t.tag_name
 ORDER BY total DESC
```

UPDATE:
Added the article ID in where clause

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `LEFT JOIN` in this case because there are probably that a tag may be *unused*.

```
SELECT  a.tag_name
FROM    tags a
        LEFT JOIN article_tags b
            ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id
GROUP   BY a.tag_name
ORDER   BY COUNT(b.tag_id) DESC
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the other query seems to work perfectly in my case. Thank you for the link too, it helped me understand a bit further about JOINs :)

Answer (score 0):

the following sql statement should give you the result you want.
replace 777 with a specific article id

```
select t.tag_name, count(at.article_tag_id) as [cnt]
from article_tags at
join tags t on (t.tag_id = at.tag_id)
join articles a on (a.article_id = at.article_id)
where a.article_id = 777
group by tag_name
order by cnt desc
```